# Error trying to add vagrant box ubuntu/wily64

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtual-machine, vagrant

For some reason I can't download the ubuntu-wily box

```
$ vagrant box add ubuntu/wily64
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/wily64'
    box: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/wily64
==> box: Adding box 'ubuntu/wily64' (v20160715.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/wily64/versions/20160715.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
    box:
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

This is strange because I can download xenial and trusty boxes with no issue:

```
$ vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64
==> box: Loading metadata for box 'ubuntu/trusty64'
    box: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/trusty64
==> box: Adding box 'ubuntu/trusty64' (v20170216.0.0) for provider: virtualbox
    box: Downloading: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty64/versions/20170216.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box
    box: Progress: 51% (Rate: 910k/s, Estimated time remaining: 0:04:04)
```

Note that I was using this box on the same setup for weeks with no issues. When I noticed the issue I tried downgrading from `1.9.1` to `1.8.7` to see if the issue was solved.. it is not.

My development machine is running windows10 64bit, and here is my vagrant version info:

```
$ vagrant version
Installed Version: 1.8.7
Latest Version: 1.9.1
```

**Edit** Just tried this on my windows7 64bit laptop and got the same error. Maybe this is a bug on hashicorp's side?

Comment: checking [the address](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/wily64/versions/20160715.0.0) in a browser indicates the box is currently unavailable.  ubuntu 15.10 is beyond end-of-life; maybe the provider has removed it?

Comment: @quixotic I believe that's probably what happened. I'm working on moving to a new version now. Thanks.

Comment: @quixotic: That's the answer, but you thought of it first: Please convert ypur comment to an answer and ping me @ Fabby so I can come back and upvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a problem on Hashicorp's side. None of the boxes under `ubuntu` that are more than a month old can be downloaded, though they're still listed on [Ubuntu's box list page](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu).

It could be the case that these boxes have been deleted from the `ubuntu` account but the box list page is being served from a cache that is outdated.

It seems that other older boxes are also gone. For example, the second most popular Ubuntu Wiley box, `larryli/wily64` (also eight months old) is also returning a 404.

If boxes are suddenly removed by official and/or reliable vendors, it's always worth checking to see if a nasty security vulnerability has suddenly come up; the boxes may have been removed to avoid it spreading further while new builds of fixed versions are being done. However, at least at the time of this edit, the most recent vulnerability in the [Ubuntu Security Notices for 15.10](https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/wily/) was over half a year ago.

That said, other boxes yet for that release, both older and newer, do seem still to work (which means it's probably not a general problem with older boxes on Atlas). Both `plainspooky/ubuntu-wily_amd64_vbox` (7 months old) and `gigerdo/ubuntu-wily` (10 months old) are still available.

Doing a [search for ubuntu and wiley](https://atlas.haThatshicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=ubuntu+wily) will give you a number of options. I typically work through them in order of popularity on the basis that something more often downloaded is more likely to have bugs or malicious code discovered in it. (Normally I try to download only from "official" accounts whenever I can.)

If you rely on having available older releases that don't have boxes from official vendors on Atlas, the safest and most reliable thing to do is to roll your own boxes (which you can upload yourself to your account on Atlas). [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) is an excellent tool for doing this.